# How to archive log directory from shell script?

Tags: ros, shell, roscd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a shell script that starts a `roslaunch` file. I use a shell script, because I provide some arguments before I start the roslaunch.

I'd like to also archive and copy the current `log` directory for the running `roscore` process. I know that by running `roscd log`, I get to the this current directory, but I cannot somehow get to this directory from the shell script.

I tried assigning it to a variable:

> log_dir=$(roscd log)

and then running `tar -zcvf $log_dir -C $output_dir`

But of course nothing is stored in my variable. I am not sure even if this is the correct approach. But I am asking here, as there might be some better ROS specific way of doing such a task.

So, what is the best way to this? Since the name of the log folder is always dynamically generated.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211187/how-to-archive-log-directory-from-shell-script?/) by [lapadets](https://answers.ros.org/users/22718/lapadets/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
roscd log
log_dir=`pwd`
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2015-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lapadets](https://answers.ros.org/users/22718/lapadets/) on 2015-06-15**:
Thank you!